# How to access pytorch embeddings lookup table as a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, tensorboard

I want to show my embeddings with the tensorboard projector. I would like to access the embeddings matrix (lookup table) of one of my layers so I can write it to the logs.

I instantiate my layer as this:

`self.embeddings_user = torch.nn.Embedding(30,300)`

And I'm looking for the tensor with shape `(30,300)` of 30 users with embedding on 300 to dimensions to replace it with the `vectors` variable in this sample code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorboard as tb
tf.io.gfile = tb.compat.tensorflow_stub.io.gfile
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

vectors = np.array([[0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,1]])
metadata = ['001', '010', '100', '111']  # labels
writer = SummaryWriter()
writer.add_embedding(vectors, metadata)
writer.close()
```

Comment: your question is not PyTorch related, better not use that tag

Comment: @JeroenVuurens Why not? my layer `self.embeddings_user = nn.Embedding(30,300)` is an embedding from pytorch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embeddings layers have weight attributes corresponding to the lookup table. You can access it as follows.

```py
vectors = self.embeddings_user.weight
```

So now you can visualize it with tensorboard.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorboard as tb
tf.io.gfile = tb.compat.tensorflow_stub.io.gfile
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

vectors = self.embeddings_user.weight
metadata = ['001', '010', '100', '111', ...]  # labels
writer = SummaryWriter()
writer.add_embedding(vectors, metadata)
writer.close()
```